# How to use texture from a specific atlas in Xcode's scene editor

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, texture-atlas, sceneeditor

Is there a way in the scene editor to select an image from a texture atlas?

I want to use an image from a texture atlas in the scene editor to create an SKSpriteNode. The problem is I have multiple atlases each containing different images with the same name.

For example, atlas1 contain image1, image2, image3, and then atlas2 also contain images named image1, image2, image3 but they are different. Only they have the same names. I want to use image1 from atlas2 but in the media library I only see image1 from atlas1 and I can't figure how to select the one in atlas2.

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: It doesn't appear that there is anyway to select the second or third etc images with the same name.

You should be able to see that 2 atlases have images with the same names <strike>and be able to pick the images out in Scene editor</strike>.

[image]

I was able to recreate this my scene editor.

Look for the little 2 beside the image, it will show that there are multiple versions (blue circle in my pic)

select your image **for viewing** with the tab like links (red circle in my image)

Also worth noting these atlases are created using .atlas folders

Comment: Yes I can see some of the other images, but I have 2 problems: the window only show a preview of the image but I can't select it to be used in a SpriteNode. Also, since I have 7 atlases, containing each size 1x, 2x and 3x, it shows "21" as the number of different images (your blue circle), and there's no way to scroll to the other images.

Comment: I think the only solution will be to use an empty node and change the texture programmatically. :(

Comment: you're right, it looks like yet another limitation/bug of Scene editor...too bad. I will revise my answer accordingly

Comment: Maybe, more functionality will get announced in 3 weeks at WWDC2017. Here's crossing our fingers

Comment: Yes! But that's nothing compared to the bugs with the animations! ;) Hopefully these problems will be addressed in the next version. Thanks for your time.